# Is there a way to display a FullCalendar event full-width behind other events in the same time-slot?

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I want to override the behaviour in FullCalendar that vertically-divides concurrent events in the same timeslot.

I have one Google calendar (called "time-blocking template") that I want all the events to occupy 100% of the timeslot width, regardless of other (non-"time-blocking") calendar events in the same timeslot. Any other events from other Google calendars are treated normally (and split-vertically if they share the same timeslot with other non-time-blocking events).

Also, non-time-blocking events need an opacity parameter so I can see the "time-blocking template" events behind them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Here's an example of what it needs to look like:
http://i.imgur.com/Guk8jVu.png

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it with FullCalendar's `eventAfterRender` function.

I over-rode the width for specific events by setting `isTemplate = "true"` for events that belong to the "Time Blocking" calendar.

Using the `eventAfterRender` function, I checked if `event.isTemplate == "true"` and set the width & left CSS accordingly. If `event.isTemplate == "false"`, I change the opacity to see the template event behind, and increment the z-index by 1 so all "non-template" events are in front of the "template events".

The following block is inside my `$('#calendar').fullCalendar()` declaration:

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if(event.isTemplate == "true") {
      $(element).css('width','100%');
      $(element).css('left','0%');
    } else {
      $(element).css('opacity','0.5');

      event_zindex = $(element).css('z-index');
      $(element).css('z-index',event_zindex + 1);
    }
```

Hope this is helpful to someone else!